# What's is the maximal size of single Memwr TLP(BAR ACCESS) from the root complex to endpoint on a X86 platform?

Tags: x86, fpga, dma, pci-e

What's is the maximal size of single Memwr TLP(BAR ACCESS) from the root complex to endpoint on a X86 platform?

The setup of my system is that there is a PCIe endpoint device plugged into an X86 PC, and the bar0 size of this device is 1 MBytes, and  this range of memory has been memory-mapped to userspace.

If I copy data to the part of memory, I could get bar access (MemWr) at the endpoint side.  But if I do a large copy  e.g. 1 MBytes,  the **Memwr** requests are always **splitted** into very small Memwr TLPs (**8bytes** or 4 bytes), that's far away from the max payload size with is **128Bytes**.

Why the root comlex splitted requests? Is this related to X86 platform?  What's is the maximal size of Memwr TLP from the root complex to endpoint on a X86 platform?

Thank you.

C

Comment: I know better performance could be achieved by using DMA.  By using DMA read we could get Cpl with 64 bytes in one TLP(for typically RCB). But, the DMA, that we are talking about here, is Direct "Host Memeory" Access. FPGA is able to access(rd/wr) "Host memory" by using DMA. 
 
My question is that, whether HOST is able to do Direct "FPGA Memeory" Access when "FPGA Memeory" is mapped to BAR address ? Based on what I observed now, the memwr from the host to FPGA is limited to 8 bytes per TLP other than MPS size.

Comment: even I use memcpy to access(wr or rd) BAR0 with a large range(e.g. 1KBytes), I still get small TLPs (<= 8 bytes). It seems the memwr requests (from HOST to FPGA) were splitted to meet a 8 bytes boundary,  other than MPS(128 bytes).

Answer (score 0):

The Max Payload Size (MPS) that is used over the link is the minimum between EPs MPS and RCs MPS. In your case, it seems as if the restricting figure here is that of the RC.

Another reason for that to happen, is if you don't have enough flow control credits (FCC) your driver can choose autonomously to split the MWr instead of waiting the FCC to reach the needed value, if they'll get there at all.

Cheers,
Nadav.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Nadav. I also think the limitation is from RC. And it should not be caused by flow control. As I only copied 1 KBytes data(memwr) to endpoint, and the bus is basically "idle" before this transfer.